# Visual C# - Drawing a circle on a panel but it doesn't shows up

Tags: c#, graphics, panel

I'm trying to do a graph maker (graph theory) but i've run into a problem, whenever i try to draw a vertex (circle) on a panel it doesn't shows up.

My paint eventhandler is the following:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Vertex v in vertices)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush_v, v.X - Vertex.Radius, v.Y - Vertex.Radius, 2 * Vertex.Radius, 2 * Vertex.Radius);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("({0},{1}), r = {2})", v.X, v.Y, Vertex.Radius));

    }
}
```

Now the message box is showing up everytime i click on the panel but the circle isn't showing up.

The code that calls panel1.Invalidate() is this:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case States.Null:
            break;
        case States.V_New:
            vertices.Add(new Vertex(e.X, e.Y));
            panel1.Invalidate();
            break;
        case States.E_New:
            break;
        case States.V_Remove:
            break;
        case States.E_Remove:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And the brush is created at the Form1 constructor:

```
brush_v = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x0F48B7));
```

I'm using VisualStudio Express 2013.

Comment: Never put a MessageBox inside a paint call.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the problem was the color of the brush.